# What is does the fscanf() format string "%30[^$]" do in C?

Tags: c, scanf

What does this format string do?

```
fscanf("%30[^$]");
```

I don't have any idea what it does, and will be so happy for an explanation of it.

Comment: Please read the *man page* for [scanf(3): input format conversion](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) before asking questions on SO regarding basic information. This is the second in less than two-days.

Answer (score 1):

`30` is the maximum input length of a string, unless `'$'` is found.

That is for a string, from a file, but you have no target string or file. Perhaps

```
char str[31];
FILE *fil = fopen("myfile.txt", "rt");
if(fil == NULL) { /* error */ }
if(fscanf(fil, "%30[^$]", str) != 1)  { /* error */ }
```

Comment: The way OP is using scanf it's UB simply.

Comment: @coderredoc more than that - it is a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

fscanf reads the data from the stream and stores it based on the parameters. As weathervane stated your code shows max length unless $ is found. You are missing a place to store it. You may find http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ useful. It shows how to format fscanf and what different specifiers like % and ^ mean.